# How to prove that square root of $x$ times $y$ is square root of $x$ times square root of $y$

Tags: roots, exponentiation

Simple question - how to prove that:

$\sqrt {x\times y} = \sqrt x \times \sqrt y$ ?

If I use the exponentation the answer seems easy, because

$(x\times y)^n = x^n \times  y^n$  because I get

$(x\times y) \times\cdots\times (x\times y)$ (where $x$ occurs $n$ times and $y$ occurs $n$ times) can be rewritten as: $x \times\cdots\times x \times y \times \cdots \times y$.

But in case of square roots that's not so obvious, because I can't rewrite the it the same way.
I can of course reason that $\sqrt x$ is $x^{\frac12}$ and $\sqrt y$ is $y^{\frac12}$ and think using induction, but that seems to not satisfy me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z:=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\ge0$ then $z^2=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\sqrt{y}=xy$ so $z=\sqrt{xy}$.

Comment: Thanks! Simple answer yet very surprising of how simple the solution is :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $n$ isn't a natural number, we can approach the proof from a different angle.

Change the square root and rewrite it as a power of a $0.5 $, then use the [power of a product rule](https://mathinsight.org/exponentiation_basic_rules#power_product) to get:

$$\sqrt{xy} = (xy)^{0.5} = x^{0.5} \cdot y^{0.5} = \sqrt x \cdot \sqrt y$$

This is true, of course, as long as $x$ and $y$ aren't negative numbers.

Comment: How do you know $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ works for $n\notin\Bbb N$?

Comment: What do you mean? Did I have to prove this in my answer? When I do algebra, I just take this as a given.

Comment: @urlyaba The OP said they don't know whether/why it *can* be taken as a given. Can you include a proof in your answer?

Comment: Happily! I'd prove it myself, but I don't think I have a clue where to start. Do you have any hints?

Comment: My answer does it in the case $n=\tfrac12$.

Comment: Oh, then I don't think it's necessary to prove the general case, as OP had already accepted the answer and the proof is quite trivial for the general case, assuming I understand your answer.